# Проблемы с Unity IAP. Null Reference Exception

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play, unity3d-android, in-app-purchases

Делаю игру на Unity (2019.2.0f1). Пытаюсь встроить покупки с помощью Unity IAP. Ключ из Google Play вставил, IAP Catalog заполнил (все как в консоли, три раза проверял), кнопку Codeless поставил (со своим кодом все точно тоже самое). При открытии приложения на Android получаю такую ошибку (пользуюсь IngameDebugConsole):

```
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Models.GooglePurchaseResult.FillPurchases (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject purchaseResult, Stores.IGoogleCachedQuerySkuDetailsService cachedQuerySkuDetailsService) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.GoogleQueryPurchasesService.QueryPurchasesWithSkuType (System.String skuType) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.GoogleQueryPurchasesService.QueryPurchases (System.Action`1[T] onQueryPurchaseSucceed) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.GooglePlayStoreService.DequeueFetchPurchases () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.Action.Invoke () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
```

Пробовал запускать и голый APK и из альфа версии в гугл плее.
Я понял, что где-то что-то кого-то не находит. А вот что, где и кого не понятно.
Скажите пожалуйста, что это может быть?

Comment: Там ошибка длиннее, но я решил сократить

Answer (score 0):

Установите версию v2.1.0, в ней нет этой ошибки. В последней пока присутствует.